# React native init method not building app in IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When I'm trying to create react native app with init like

```
react-native init AppName
```

Above created project with name AppName, then I'm trying to build the app in IOS it's getting failed.

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

I have tried [https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5054#issuecomment-264718211](http://solutions) all these steps and upgraded node, react-native.

But still, I'm getting the same issue. I'm using below versions.

```
node version: v10.10.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.1
```

Answer (score 1):

They fixed this issue in RN 0.58+. So a simple upgrade should fix it.